# Fluent API for navigation property in the two ways

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, fluent, fluent-interface

## Classes

```
public class ProductType
{
    public Guid ID { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Categories { get; set }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    public Guid ID { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

### Configuration

**ProductTypeConfiguration**

```
HasMany(p => p.Categories).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

### Question

Note the properties `Categories` and `ProductType`

The relationship is one (ProductType) to many (ProductCategory), however, a `ProductCategory` is associated with a single `ProductType`!

In my database it is creating two FKS!!
How would the configuration (**using FluentAPI**) for this type of situation??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HasMany(p => p.Categories)
    .WithRequired(c => c.ProductType) // specify inverse navigation property here
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

If you omit the lambda for the navigation property in `WithRequired` EF assumes that `Category.ProductType` belongs to another second relationship - which is the reason for the second foreign key in your database table.